How do I get hair particles to lay flat on an object?
I'm trying to create a procedural material for a sort of fibre based particle board, but I don't have the physical object so I need to create a material for it from scratch.
The picture below (side edges) sort shows what I'm trying to create, which is a sort of dense fluff with the odd longer strand that sits on the surface.
I'm reasonably happy with the main body of the material ( pale yellow bit ) but have tried using hair particles to create the longer strands. What I need to do is to get the longer strands ( coloured pink for visibility ) is to lie flat (ish) on the surface of the sphere.
I've tried messing about with the roughness, but no luck, so instead I've tried creating a vortex force field inside of the sphere to attract the hairs to the surface, but most of them disappear and the ones that remain stick up too much.
If anyone can help I'd really appreciate it! Thank you in advance!
Setup and file below :)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/19uSEF2Rl_n5cq6dXrtiqK58WN0MUXNBA/view?usp=sharing

What about switching to Particle edit mode and simply comb them as desired?

If you don't mind using the new Hair Curves you can use the Shrinkwrap modifier
